# Derive the generating function for canonical transformation of type $F_3$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hamiltonian-formalism

I'm working on some practice questions and I am a bit confused with this one:

> Generating functions of the type $F_1(q,Q)$ satisfy the condition: 
>    $$pdq-PdQ = dF_1$$ Starting from this condition derive the analogous
>    result for the generating functions of type $F_3(q,P)$.

I must admit, I am a little confused with the Legendre transform and how the other generating functions are derived.

Here is what I have tried by following my textbook,

Applying the Legendre transform with respect to the new coordinates and momenta to $F_1$:

$$ d(\sum QP + F_1) = PdQ + QdP + pdq-PdQ = QdP + pdq = dF_2 $$

Which seems correct for $F_2$. (I'm not even sure if I have done this correctly, I'm pretty much just following my textbook). To get $dF_3$, my textbook just says perform the Legendre transform with respect to the 'other' variables?

However, I'm not sure what this means?. I know I am expecting to get $-qdp-PdQ$, but just not too sure about what I am doing.

**ADDED:**

I think I may have gotten a little further with my understanding. If I take the legendre transform of $F_1$ with respect to the old coordinate $q$ and it's conjugate momenta, then:

$$F_1 - pq = F_3$$ so, $$d(F_1 - pq) = pdq-PdQ-qdp-pdq = -qdp-PdQ = dF_3$$

Which seems to be correct. But then isn't

$$d(F_1 - QP) = pdq-PdQ-QdP-PdQ $$ which is not $dF_2$. Where am I going wrong? How would I say, derive $dF_4$? By definition of the legendre transform, is it true that for instance if $G$ is the legendre transform of $F$, i.e. $G=F-wy$, the pair $w,y$ must always be a conjugate pair (i.e $w=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})$?

Comment: Hi JackReacher. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, Legendre transform is just "integrate by parts". So, from $pdq - PdQ =F_1$, we have $pdq -d(PQ)+QdP =dF_1$, i.e., $pdq +QdP =d(F_1+PQ) \equiv dF_2$. The "Transform" means after "integration by parts", we need to change the independent variables. For example, in $F_1$, $p=p(q,Q)$ but in $F_2$, $p=p(q,P)$. So we need to solve $Q = Q(q,P)$ and insert in to $p=p(q,Q(q,P))$ to get $p(q,P)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm still confused, and to be honest still confused about the definition of a legendre transform. My understanding so far is that the definition of the Legendre transform of a function $f(x,y)$ is $G = f-wy$ where $w= \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ - and then this can be done with a few combinations of variables. I'm a bit confused as to why differentials come into play?

Comment: we have $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy \equiv u dx + wdy$

Comment: Thanks, I think I have gotten a little further with my understanding, could you look at my edit in my question, if you are able to help me?

Comment: $F_2 = F_1 +PQ$ rather than minus...

Comment: So for a Legendre transform, does the sign not matter? In that sense, how is one supposed to know how to derive the other generating functions? Just by guess/memorization? For example, if I wanted to derive $F_4$, I have already done $F_2 = F_1 + PQ$, $F_3 = F_1 - qp$, aren't these the only conjugate variables? Can you do also $pP$? But then aren't these not conjugate to each other? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: The sign is very important. As you can see in my deriviation, the sign can be derived by "integration by parts". For example, $dE = TdS - pdV$, $d(E+PV) = TdS + vdp, d(E-TS) = -SdT - pdv$... The point is the independent variable appears as the $d ..$

Comment: Sorry, still not really getting it, I may be thinking about this in the opposite direction. Here is my thought process: We start with a function $f(x,y)$ and wish to perform a Legendre transform. if we take the differential we get: $df = udx + wdy$, then my notes say, compute the differential $d(wy)$ - I guess my question is why $wy$? When I compute this, I'm having trouble seeing why its the same as integration by parts?

Comment: $df=udx+wdy$, $df = udx + d(wy) - ydw$. So we need to compute the differential $d(wy)$... If you really want to know legedre transformation, you can read Arnold's book to find its geometric meanings. But in practice, what you need to remember is that legedre transformation is just "integration by parts".

Comment: I guess I am not so much worried about the geometric meaning at the moment. I'm just confused with how we form the different generating functions from $F_1$. For example, I get $F_2$ by doing $F_1 + QP$, and I get $F_3$ by doing $F_1 - qp$, how would i get $F_4$? And how do we know that $F_2, F_3$ could be formed by adding/subtracting those conjugate coordinates?

Comment: Please read carefully what I have done in the dE example. I think you can understand this by calculating by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This here is not exactly an answer, but a clarification of why Legendre transforms are not needed to get this result. Using exterior derivatives is much easier.

If you have $pdq - PdQ = dF$, take the exterior derivative on both sides to get $dp \wedge dq - dP \wedge dQ = 0$ (the exterior derivative of a differential is zero). The wedge product is antisymmetric, so $dp \wedge dq - dP \wedge dQ  = dp \wedge dq + dQ \wedge dP =0$. Take now the 1-form whose exterior derivative gives us $dp \wedge dq + dQ \wedge dP =0$, that is, $pdq + QdP = dG$. This means that

$$\partial_q G(q,P) = p \\
\partial_P G(q,P) = Q ,$$

and that's the answer. The Legendre transform is just a cumbersome way of transforming variables in 1-forms instead of using the much simpler structure of the 2-forms.